# Auto keying in real time works incorrectly with inverse kinematics

Tags: animation, keyframes, inverse-kinematics

When recording an IK chain's motion in real time, the resulting animation does not match what was gestured during recording.

What I gestured: [image: what I gestured]

What I got: [image: what I got]

Is this a bug or am I missing something? I'm inclined to believe it's a bug, especially since experimenting with the problem previously yielded different (but still wrong) results.

#### TECHNICAL DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM

Auto keying is enabled and set to "Add & Replace". "Only Active Keying Set" and "Layered Recording" are turned off. Blender version is 3.6.

I press Play Animation, moving a bone at the tail of an IK chain while the animation plays. The result - as evident during playback - is as follows.

The tail bone's motion (relative to its parent) is recorded correctly, but for the other bones in the IK chain, the only keyframe recorded is at the very end of the motion, representing the given bone's final state.

This pattern seems to occur regardless of the timeline's other contents.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Your IK constraint is not properly configured.  You need to specify a target for the IK constraint.  Then, you move and keyframe that target.

Comment: @Nathan Thank you, that worked. I still find the behavior as I described it strange, but your solution does make the problem disappear. Thanks again.

Comment: The fact that it does anything at all when not fully set up is kind of an accident.  It's just not ready until you give it a target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nathan said, the problem can be solved by specifying a target for the IK constraint, and moving and keyframing that target, instead of the tail bone itself.